# How to Properly Schedule Quartz.Net Jobs on Runtime on ASP.NET 6.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, quartz.net

I'm trying to build an admin panel using ASP.NET Core 6.0 where I can add and modify quartz.net job triggers on runtime, but all documentation and examples I can find configure triggers as hardcoded on program.cs and are not modifiable by the end user. Ideally, I would want to build an html interface that is similar to an alarm clock settings menu with days of week and hour to trigger, convert it to a cron expression on the backend (controller) and add a new trigger to the scheduler. I think I should use Dependency Injection but couldn't figure out the correct way to do that.

Any suggestions?

The project is intended to run on a Raspberry Pi to schedule and automate some relays and stuff at the end.

I have gone through quartz.net official documentation. There are pages about DI and asp.net core integration but not any examples on how to schedule on runtime. I also searched google and couldn't find any examples of what I'm trying to do. All examples show how to schedule on program.cs or startup.cs, which is only useful for hard coding some schedules.

Comment: This is a strange question, the same code that you use to schedule jobs in the examples **is** runtime code, so are you asking how to write a UI to allow you to do this? At the moment the question is unclear...

Comment: Maybe I should clarify, I want to write a service that can utilize the scheduler anytime while the app is running. Examples I find usually do it while configuring the quartz service at program.cs such as https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/aspnet-core-integration.html#a-practical-example-of-the-setup

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the following

There are some UI options there
https://code.google.com/archive/p/quartznet-admin/

https://github.com/mausch/QuartzNetWebConsole

https://github.com/jlucansky/Quartzmin

https://github.com/adometry/QuartzNetManager

These are the open source example of UI. You can the inspiration from them and create your own if you don't like them already.

Best way to do it from the AppSetting that I can have explain at following.

Most of the time you wanted to set that via cron jobs like the following.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddQuartz(q =>  
        {
            q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionScopedJobFactory();

            // Create a "key" for the job
            var jobKey = new JobKey("HelloWorldJob");

            // Register the job with the DI container
            q.AddJob<HelloWorldJob>(opts => opts.WithIdentity(jobKey));
            
            // Create a trigger for the job
            q.AddTrigger(opts => opts
                .ForJob(jobKey) // link to the HelloWorldJob
                .WithIdentity("HelloWorldJob-trigger") // give the trigger a unique name
                .WithCronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?")); // run every 5 seconds

        });
        services.AddQuartzHostedService(q => q.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);
        // ...
    });
```

Here is "WithCronSchedule" whatever configuration you have put there you can put that in AppSettings.json.

So in the future, if you want to change it you don't need to deploy it again. If you don't know how to work with Appsettings you can read following documentation from Microsoft you can read that string from appsettings

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Here is one more
https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/asp-net-core-appsettings-json-file/

You can put like following

```
"CronsSettings": {
    "CronString": "0/5 * * * * ?",
}
```

Now you can create classes like following

```
public class CronsSettings
{
    public string CronString{ get; set; }
}
```

Then in Startup.cs file you can fetch it like following

```
var cronSettings= builder.Configuration.GetSection("CronSettings").Get<CronSettings>();
string cronString= settings.CronString;
```

now you can use that here.

```
q.AddTrigger(opts => opts
            .ForJob(jobKey) // link to the HelloWorldJob
            .WithIdentity("HelloWorldJob-trigger") // give the trigger a unique name
            .WithCronSchedule(cronSettings)); // run every 5 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for your long and detailed answer. However maybe my question wasn't clear. I as the developer can edit appsetings.json, but what I'm trying to do is make a user interface so that user can add/edit schedules with http requests. Therefore setting schedules on launch doesn't work for me.